# SQL calculation problem in snowflake -programming problem

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with given columns GroupID,ID,event_time_local (timestamp - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss data type), event_type :

[image: table data]

I need to calculate the column "event_number" as shown in the picture.
it should be calculated for each partition of [GroupID,ID]

I wrote the following pseudo code for calculation (hope its o.k, because I didn't check it yet to run on entire table which contain 160,000,000 rows )

```
for each [GrpId,ID]
cnt = 1 
event_number = 1 
    for each row ordered by event_time_local ascending:
          if event_type = first_event then event_number = 1 
          elif event_type = event and (previous_event_type =event or is null) then 
                             event_number = event_number + 1
                             cnt = cnt + 1
          if event_type=double_event  then 
                             event_number = event_number + 0.1
         if event_type=event  and prev_event =double event  then 
                              event_number = cnt + 1 
                              cnt = cnt + 1
```

my question is what is the best strategy to calculate this column in snowflake to get elegant code that will be easy to maintain with and efficient running time.

I have tried to do it with window functions and it got complicated.. and not elegant code.

I'll Appreciate any help with this,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to define the groupings and then some arithmetic to do what you want.  Basically, you need:

- a group id for each "first event" grouping
- an enumeration of the "event" within each group.
- an enumeration of the "event double" within each "event" group.

The groups can be defined using cumulative sums.  The rest are ranking functions:

```
select t.*,
       (dense_rank() over (partition by group_id, id, fe_grp order by e_grp) ||
        (case when event_type = 'event double'
              then  '.' || row_number() over (partition by group_id, id, fe_grp, e_grp order by event_time_local)
              else ''
         end)
        ) as event_number
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when event_type = 'First event' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by groupid, id order by event_time_local) as fe_grp,
             sum(case when event_type in ('First event', 'event') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by groupid, id order by event_time_local) as e_grp
       from t
      ) t;
```